# Why is Magento Creating Files with 666 Permissions?

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, acl

Magento creates all new files with 666 permissions. It is driving me nuts trying to figure out how to stop this behavior.

I've set up Nginx & php5-fcgi on Ubuntu 14.04 to operate as follows:

Owner: someuser
Group: www-data

Nginx is operating as www-data. Chmod recursively on /var/www 660 for files and 770 for directories.

I set group bit (+s) so that all files belong to group "www-data". 'Someuser' belongs to this group. This allows me to upload / edit files as someuser while letting www-data have full access to them.

I installed ACL and ran this command:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::--- /var/www
```

I've confirmed the ACL and group bit is set properly for new files that I create myself. I also created a PHP script to create some new files and confirmed that PHP is creating files with correct permissions (660).

So everything seems to be set up properly, except Magento insists on creating files with 666 permissions. There are numerous places in Magento where it sets umask to 0. I'm not sure if this is the source of the issue.

Otherwise I have no idea. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about servers.

Comment: No, it's about Magento's behavior of setting masks and permissions for files that it creates.

Comment: For the glory of Satan of course! On a serious note, what files are you talking about specifically?

Comment: Any files that Magento creates: so, for example, 1) sitemap files; and 2) files for modules installed via Magento Connect. Not sure about cache / session files because I'm using Redis for the cache so there are no cache / session files on my system.

Comment: For log files (e.g. exception.log), it creates them with 777 permissions.

Comment: It's probably a whole lot simpler to run Nginx as a different user.